# Sql server get only the date from a DateTime and filter on it

Tags: sql-server

I have a database in Sql Server with TimeSpan column the date in the TimeSpan column format is : 14/03/2022 18:50:21

I was looking for a way how to sort the data by day and month. The only problem is i have also time included into the database which seems to be an issue to filter on. Somehow i'm not able to only filter by days/months. Its not giving me an error which i understand i just need a wat to provide a time...

I've tried :

**With wild cards.**

```
Select * from MBR where TAG='FT_AV_03' AND TimeStamp LIKE '03/14/2022 __:__:__' 

Select * from MBR where TAG='FT_AV_03' AND TimeStamp LIKE '03/15/2022 %'
```

**With Contains**

```
select * from MBR where TimeStamp like '03/15/2022%'
```

Comment: could you please clarify the datatype of the TimeSpan column.

Comment: `the TimeSpan column format is` There is no format in the database for time/date columns

Comment: select * from MBR where convert(date, TimeStamp) = '20220315'

Comment: @GuidoG This is [not the way I would recommend it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/1186).

Comment: @Sergey Bruh?? DateTime ofcourse

Comment: https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, don't ever do `TimeStamp LIKE <anything>` because it's not a string. You want a range query so that SQL Server doesn't have to do anything to the column first (like convert it to a different type or translate it into a specific format), and potentially use an index (now or if one exists in the future):

```
WHERE [TimeStamp] >= '20220314'
  AND [TimeStamp] <  '20220315';
```

As for sorting, well, it's not quite clear what you want. It could be simply:

```
ORDER BY [TimeStamp];
```

But if you want to order rows within a specific day by something else, if you've already filtered to just that day, then just `ORDER BY <that>`. If you want something else, you'll need to be more specific.

- [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates)